# Exception Cannot find the library com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library, required by the application /xsp/Domino9Test

Tags: xpages

We have installed domino 9 Server, copied existing xPages based application on Server. Did some minor changes on Designer 9.0.1 when try to run on Lotus Notes Client. 8.5.2 received following exception.

Exception
Cannot find the library com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library, required by the application /xsp/Domino9Test!!ClientDb.nsf

Removed all controls created in 9.0.1 and saved all design element in 8.5.2 but still same exception when try to open application in 8.5.2 client. Moreover nothing used in code new in 9.0.1.

Server 9.0.1 and client 8.5.2

Please guide and tell us safe method to migrate application from 8.5.2 to 9.0.

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Qaiser

Comment: Check your Application Properties, and verify that the XPages Libraries are checked for the Ext Lib.  In 8.5.3, the XSP Properties and the Application Properties were combined.

Answer (score 2):

In the XSP Properties there's an option for "Minimum supported release". I've never used it but try setting that to 8.5.2 and doing a clean and re build.

I would think any app should run fine on the server but it sounds like you're having a problem with the client?  That might get dicey.  I don't believe there was an Ext. Library available in 8.5.2 - I forget when that came in. but it's now built into 9.*.  So it's a big difference as far as clients go.

If you really have to support XPiNC in 8.5.2 and I feel bad for you if you do as that was really "beta" in my opinion, but if you do then I would only touch the app with an 8.5.2 designer....

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply on this issue. I personally think if application is deployed on 9.0.1 and using client 8.5.x whether you have used extension lib or not  it may create problem if you have saved designed elements in 9.0.x. So this is causing the issue. In current scenario application is deployed on 9.0.1 and code is same as we were using in 8.5.3 FP6 its running well on Client 9.x but not running in downgraded version. Let me try XSP properties and get back to you. Thanks againf or your time.